# Getting Grid cell information on Left Mouse Button Down

Tags: c#, silverlight, grid, mouseevent

Greetings,

I'm having a Grid to which I add rows and columns according to data given by the user.

Now I wish to have a event that captures the location of my mouseclick by row and column.
So when I click in column 5 of row 2 I wish to get exactly that information in my code behind.

However all I'm getting so far is args.OriginalSource = {System.Windows.Controls.Grid}

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Xaml:

```
<Grid Background="White" x:Name="MainSchedular">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="33" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="33">
        <ColumnDefinition Width="33">
        <ColumnDefinition Width="33">
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
this.MouseLeftButtonDown += (se, eas) =>
{
    //some code here that captures the row and column position
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case people are wondering how: 
I've managed to do this by creating a button and placing in the top left corner of the Grid.

Using this button as reference for MouseButtonEventsArgs.GetPosition I can then calculate which row and column I clicked by:

```
double rowheigth = 0, columnlength = 0;
int row = 0, column = 0;
if (pos.X > this.TheGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth && pos.Y > this.TheGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight)
{
    while (rowheigth + this.TheGrid.RowDefinitions[row].ActualHeight < pos.Y)
    {
        rowheigth += this.TheGrid.RowDefinitions[row].ActualHeight;
        row++;
    }
    while (columnlength + this.TheGrid.ColumnDefinitions[column].ActualWidth < pos.X)
    {
        columnlength += this.TheGrid.ColumnDefinitions[column].ActualWidth;
        column++;
    }
}
```